# Using @RequestMapping(headers = "Accept=application/json") in SpringMVC4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 4 and I want to know that I am using `@RestController` at class level and for one of its method I am  Using `@RequestMapping(headers = "Accept=application/json")`. Now can any one tell me why just by using `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in my `config-servlet.xml` how I am getting the response in `JSON` on my browser. I mean using header attribute is only saying that this method can only respond to requests having this type of  headers. How does the MVC4 knows to respond in `JSON` on browser. Here is my code:

**My config-servlet.xml**

```
<beans>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.songs.service.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

**My RestController Class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/songappWS")
public class SongServiceWS 
{ 
@RequestMapping(value = "/topmoviesWS", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
public List<?> getTopMoviesWS() {
//method logic
return l1;

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason Spring is responding in JSON is that `@RestController` implicitly means that the the response of `getTopMoviesWS()` method is handled as if it had the `@ResponseBody` annotation (already present in Spring 3).

What that means is that Spring will use the Jackson JSON library (if present on the classpath) to convert the response to JSON.

Check out [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest) post.

Comment: Is this like spring automatically chooses to return in JSON by default

Comment: When `@ResponseBody` is present or when using `RestController` and if Jackson is on the classpath, then yes, Spring MVC will return JSON

Answer (score 3):

You get the response in JSON because of @RestController, How??

1. `@RestController` is itself annotated with `@Controller` and
   `@ResponseBody` implying that  `@RequestMapping` methods assume
   `@ResponseBody` semantics by default.You can have more information [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api//org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html).

To be more comprehensive, your code will look like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/topmoviesWS", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
  headers="Accept=application/json")   
public @ResponseBody List<?> getTopMoviesWS() { 

   return l1;    
}
```

1. the `@ResponseBody` annotation on the `getTopMoviesWS()` method tells Spring MVC that it does not need to render the response through a server-side view layer, but that instead  the list returned is the response body, and should be written out directly  to the HTTP response as JSON.
   The list returned must be converted to JSON, you don’t need to do this conversion manually. Because Jackson 2 is on the classpath, Spring’s `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is automatically chosen to convert the values to JSON.
   You can have a look [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) to understand the `@ResponseBody` mechanism.

Comment: Thankyou.Now I know that by default spring chooses to return in JSON

Comment: don't mention it :)
I think you should close this topic by approving a answer or writing the right one and approve it.

Comment: **can you answer this also**  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624909/how-to-return-json-from-spring-restful-service-and-access-it-using-resttemplate

Comment: **Please answer to this question** alsohttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644452/how-to-access-a-huge-json-coming-from-a-spring-restful-service-in-a-spring-mvc