# How to return JSON from spring RESTful service and access it using RestTemplate class

Tags: spring, rest

I made a spring RESTful web service for giving list of top songs in JSON formate, for this  I added song names in a List and I returned this from the @Restcontroller of my Spring RESTful web service.SO @RestController will automatically process this List and rturns me this JSON form ["song1","song2","song3"].

**Now can any body tell me how I can return song names with some more attribute like**
 - (Song Name , Film, Lyricist, Singer(s), Total hits)
For Example - (“Lungi Dance”, “Chennai Express”, "Honey Singh", "Honey Singh”, 5000).**Also tell me how can I access it my  spring MVC application calling this web service using RestTemplate.** 
Please tell me the changes in below files.

**Inside my @RestController class of my Spring RESTful web service**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/topsongsWS", headers="Accept=application/json")
    Public List<?> getTopSongsWS() 
    {
            List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            l1.add("mann mera (Table No 21)");
            l1.add("Lazy lad (Ghanchakkar)");
            l1.add("Oye boy Charlie (Matru Ki Bijli Ka Mandola)");
            l1.add("Blue Hai Pani Pani");
            l1.add("Latt lag gayi (Race 2)");
            return l1;
    }
```

**Inside my config-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.songs.service.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

**Inside the controller of my spring MVC app calling this above RESTful web service**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/topsongs",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getTopSongs(ModelMap md)
    { 
            //did stuff to configure headers & entity
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

            //this is the URL of my RESTfulservice returning JSON format    ["song1","song2","song3"]   
            String url="http://localhost:7001/SongAppWS/songappWS/topsongsWS";
            RestTemplate rt=new RestTemplate();
            ResponseEntity<?> listoftopmovies=rt.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET,entity, List.class);
            md.addAttribute("listname", "Top 5 Songs of The Week:");
            String response=listoftopmovies.getBody().toString();
            List<String> listed = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(response.split(", ")));
            md.addAttribute("res",listed);
            return "Sucess";
    }
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need `getTopSongsWS` to return `List<Song>`, not `List<?>`. This involves actually creating this domain object to suit your requirements. It's not clear why you're calling your own REST endpoint from another controller instead of directly using its backing service. Either way the question is too broad as it touches many concepts and it seems that you're missing some basics, I suggest having a look at [Spring guides](https://spring.io/guides) to see how to properly layer your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return your songs with more attribute, you should create a resource representation class.In your case,it could look like

```
class Song {
private String name
private String film
//other fields and methods...
```

Then in your restfull ws

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/topsongsWS", headers="Accept=application/json")
public List<?> getTopSongsWS() 
{
        List<Song> l1 = new ArrayList<Song>();
        l1.add(new Song(atr1,atr2....));
        l1.add(new Song(atr1,atr2....));
        l1.add(new Song(atr1,atr2....)); 
        return l1;
}
```

In your spring mvc app, you should have too the resource representation class, and the response type will now be `Song` instead of `String` 
To consume your ws, this should work

```
@RequestMapping(value="/topsongs",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String getTopSongs(ModelMap md)
{ 
String url="http://localhost:7001/SongAppWS/songappWS/topsongsWS";
RestTemplate rt=new RestTemplate();
Song[] songs = template.getForObject(url, Song[].class); 

md.addAttribute("listname", "Top 5 Songs of The Week:");
md.addAttribute("res", Arrays.asList(songs));  
return "Sucess";
```

}

Comment: Thankyou it solved my **first question** and my RESTful WS is returning the JSON I asked for but for my 2nd question when I am accessing this JSON its showing **no suitable HttpMessageConverter found**

Comment: **Please answer to this question also** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644452/how-to-access-a-huge-json-coming-from-a-spring-restful-service-in-a-spring-mvc

Comment: @user3626306 i just edited my post in order to address your 2nd question about how to consume your web service using `RestTemplate`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use model class like  List

Please have a look this below source code in github. It has json response as object. Hope it will help.
https://github.com/mohansaravanan/spring
https://github.com/mohansaravanan/spring/tree/master/springmvc-3.2.2